# couldn't install gopls in Fedora 31

Tags: go

I've below go version

```
$ go version
go version go1.14.3 linux/amd64

$ which 
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

GOPATH is set as

```
    $ echo $GOPATH
    /home/raj/go
```

PATH variable is set as -

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/raj/.cargo/bin:/home/raj/go/bin:/home/raj/.cabal/bin:/home/raj/.ghcup/bin:/home/raj/.cargo/bin:/home/raj/.cabal/bin:/home/raj/.ghcup/bin:/home/raj/.cabal/bin:/home/raj/.ghcup/bin:/home/raj/.cargo/bin:/home/raj/.cabal/bin:/home/raj/.ghcup/bin:/home/raj/.cargo/bin:/home/raj/.cabal/bin:/home/raj/.ghcup/bin:/home/raj/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin:/home/raj/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/home/raj/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:/home/raj/.cargo/bin:/home/raj/.cabal/bin:/home/raj/.ghcup/bin:/home/raj/.local/bin:/home/raj/bin:/home/raj/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/raj/bin:/home/raj/Deps/cmake/3.16.5/cmake/bin/:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/raj/bin:/home/raj/Deps/cmake/3.16.5/cmake/bin/:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/raj/bin:/home/raj/Deps/cmake/3.16.5/cmake/bin/
```

As you can see `/home/raj/go/bin` is in PATH

Now, I'm trying to install `gopls` and I'm getting below error -

> $ GO111MODULE=on go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
>   go: golang.org/x/tools/gopls latest => v0.4.1
>   runtime/internal/atomic
>
> ## runtime/internal/atomic
>
> /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:13:6: Load redeclared in this block
>          previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:16:24
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:19:6: Loadp redeclared in this block
>          previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:22:32
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:25:6: Load64 redeclared in this block
>          previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:28:26
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:31:6: LoadAcq redeclared in this block
>          previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:34:27
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:36:6: Xadd redeclared in this block
>          previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:39:37
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:39:6: Xadd64 redeclared in this block
>          previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:42:39
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:42:6: Xadduintptr redeclared in this block
>          previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:45:47
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:45:6: Xchg redeclared in this block
>          previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:48:36
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:48:6: Xchg64 redeclared in this block
>          previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:51:38
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:51:6: Xchguintptr redeclared in this block
>          previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:54:45
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:51:6: too many errors

Why I'm getting this error and how can I fix this?

Note: My OS details are -

```
    $ lsb_release -a
    LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
    Distributor ID: Fedora
    Description:    Fedora release 31 (Thirty One)
    Release:        31
    Codename:       ThirtyOne
```

Comment: You have a broken Go installation; clean out GOROOT and install the correct source tree.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jimb commented, I removed the go installation `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go` and reinstalled go and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem and in my case the problem was that i had installed the package `gcc-go` which for some reason didn't work with the Vscode extensions, but when i removed it and instead downloaded the package `golang` everything worked instantly. Maybe this can help someone.